# How to run django app without settings.py

Tags: django, settings

I am new to django and looking into already created django sites with source code and wants to see on how it runs. After downloading one of them, I realised there is no settings.py in the folder itself. Having already created simple sites with mod_wsgi and apache, I am not sure how to run this particular site with a template system. Seems there are websites on how to run customised settings, but I am not sure on how to go about running the site. Appreciate any tips on how to go about running the downloaded django site with source codes.

Is it also possible and if it is correct, to create a settings.py file for this kind of sites? 
Thanks

[Link to download django site](https://github.com/marcinn/django-photo-gallery)

Answer (score 4):

Django apps are *not* intended to be runnable; they must be integrated into a Django project in order to be used. See the [Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) for more details.

Comment: and if you want to see how an app works you need to stat a new project or add it to an exsiting project. (so sometimes they have an online demo).